# Windows 10 no longer boots after C: partition is moved

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, uefi

I triple boot elementary OS, arch Linux, and Windows 10

I recently changed all my partitions around. Both Linux installs still boot fine. Windows, however, freezes during boot and then kicks me to recovery mode

I don't have windows installation media as the key to activate windows is tied to my laptop (came pre-activated)

My laptop runs in 64bit EFI mode and any solutions I could find require a pc Booting in Bios mode

Obviously I'd also rather not lose everything. Is there anything I can do to recover from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what solved the problem but here goes

I chkdsk the system and EFI partitions

I manually resized the partition with diskpart (shrunk by 1GB)

Ran boot repair, didn't reinstall grub though

Something in this resolved the issue and now windows boots fine